# How to add a new module position in joomla 3.X

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, templates

I am trying to add a new module position to the top of my joomla template. I have followed all of the steps outlined in this article:
https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla-templates/customizing-joomla-template/how-to-add-new-module-position.

However, when I get to the final step, the module is never in the exact position where I want it. I need the module to be in the upper right section of the page for a login box.

Can anyone provide information on what I am missing to place the module exactly where I want it to be?
Thanks!

Comment: The question is too vague. A link to your URL with a picture of the problem would at least make it possible to answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that when you say `the module is never in the exact position where I want it`, it means your new module position *is* rendered, but not the way you expect.

As the tutorial you've used mention:

> To make the module match the look of the template, you may need to adjust the CSS files

You probably need to position the `<div>` correctly using CSS. An exact answer is not possible unless you can give access to a live site, tell us what template you're using, or at least provide a screenshot. But first of all I suggest you check your source code or Firebug/Chrome Developer tools (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, or <kbd>F12</kbd>) and see if your module HTML is rendered where you expected.

If it is, then you will have to play around with CSS in order to position it correctly. [This page](http://learnlayout.com/position.html) has an introduction on how to position elements using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The templateDetails.xml file contains all the installation and core information for a template. In order for module positions to be available for selection in the Module Manager, the positions must be declared in the templateDetails.xml file of the template.

```
<positions>
  <position>top</position>
  <position>left</position>
  <position>right</position>                
  <position>bottom</position>
  <position>banner</position>
  <position>syndicate</position>
  <position>footer</position>
  <position>user1</position>
  <position>user2</position>
  <position>user3</position>
  <position>user4</position>
  <position>debug</position>
</positions>
```

Know more - https://docs.joomla.org/Declaring_module_positions